# Minimum possible sum of weights of the heaviest and the $2^{nd}$ heaviest kid

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, contest-math, average

**Question**:

> The average weight of any $2$ kids in a group of $6$ kids is a distinct natural number. The minimum weight of any kid is $11$ kg. Find the minimum possible sum of the weights of the heaviest and the $2^{nd}$ heaviest kid in the group.

**Solution**:

> By **hit and try** we get the values as $11,13,15,19,25,35$ kgs.
> As after taking $11,13,15$ we can't take $17$, so next take $19$ and so on.

Is there any other (better, that is, more logical) way to do this question (without hit and try)? 
Because the hit and try approach is too time taking.

Comment: My first impression is that there is no efficient solution. Maybe, it is related somehow to the subsetsum problem.

Comment: The weights obviously all have the same parity, so they are all odd. That's about all you can get without trial and error.

Comment: @TheBestMagician yeah, figured that much, that's why went from 17 to 19 but inspite of it, it's time taking. I thought/expected a more... maybe insightful/procedural way to do it. Like if there's some series/pattern followed by such numbers or whether we may first jot down the natural numbers for various distinct averages and then work towards solution. Or none of the above but something completely different and wonderful.

Comment: OEIS search result for the given numbers [was this](https://oeis.org/search?q=11%2C13%2C15%2C19%2C25%2C35&language=english&go=Search). Though this is not it (the answer I'm looking for).

Answer (score 2):

A relevant OEIS sequence is http://oeis.org/A080430.
"a(n) = least odd number such that all pairwise sums a(i) + a(j), i < j <= n, are distinct."

That sequence starts $1,3,5,9,15,25$, ... We can add $10$ to each value there to get values for the given problem here. Adding a constant to every term does not affect the uniqueness of the pairwise sums.

Beyond the $6$th term, that sequence does not give us the correct answer. By using only the next lowest possible number at each step we are only considering the lowest possible weight for the heaviest kid, but we want the lowest possible sum of weights for the two heaviest kids

$\{11, 13, 15, 19, 27, 37, 47\}$ is the best solution for $7$ kids.
$\{11, 13, 15, 19, 27, 39, 49, 59\}$ is the best solution for $8$ kids.

These were found using a brute force program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1. Didn't see that there's optimization issue for the lowest possible sum of weights for 2 heaviest kids. Though still, this makes the question even more time consuming and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Partial Answer:

Start with $11,13,15$ obviously and let them belong to the set $S$ (arranged in ascending order). Then all we need to be concerned with is $3$ numbers: $S_1, S_{n-1}, S_n$ (where last 2 terms represent the last 2 elements from set $S$).

**Then the next term to be included in the set $S$ is given by:**
$$\bf S_{n+1}=S_n+S_{n-1}-S_1+2$$

So, the next term after $15$ is: $=15+13-11+2=19$
Similarly the next term is given by: $=19+15-11+2=25$
And finally the last term is given by: $=25+19-11+2=35$

---

**The logic:** 
The term $S_{n+1}$ should be such:
$$\frac{S_n+S_{n-1}}{2}+1=\frac{S_{n+1}+S_1}{2}$$

---

If anybody's interested in knowing the $1^{st}$ $25$ such numbers, they are as follows:
[image]

 (Click to enlarge the image.)

Comment: Above is a "partial answer" as it is not "efficient" in a way that, as user @nickgard points out, it won't give the lowest possible sum of weights for the 2 heaviest kids.

Comment: Some similar sequences: [A080430](http://oeis.org/A080430); [A001595](https://oeis.org/A001595); [A005282](https://oeis.org/A005282)